# Update nodejs on windows without restarting server

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to update my nodejs from version 0.10 to 4.4 on a windows server, when trying to install with the .msi it lets the user know that a restart will be required to finish the installation. Is there any way to update nodejs WITHOUT having to restart the server?

Comment: On such a upgrade, you want a maintenance time to make sure nothing go wrong. Especially in production. And as of your question, I highly doubt that.